# Component and linker library

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries

Now I am reading [documentation](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/LHCb/LHCbSoftwareTrainingBasics#Configuration_Management_Tool) and come across these concepts:

```
# Define link options and environment variables for loading component library
# Define link options and environment variables for loading linker library
```

What are component library and linker library? (Googling hasn't given me any sensible results)

Comment: Not related to a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Those are fundamentally different concepts which breaks down to the following:

When you use code parts of a component library (suffix .a), those become an integral part of the resulting binary. The library itself is not needed any more then.

A "linker library" is linked dynamically at runtime (suffix .so) and the code used from it is *not* part of your binary. You (resp. your system environment) will have to provide the shared library (or a compatible one) at runtime.